# Pass a pre-defined config array of validator names to a form component

Tags: angular, validation, angular-forms

I am trying to create a dynamic form in Angular 4. Each field will use an independent component, and will need to be passed configuration data including a list of validators, all pre-set server-side.

I am struggling to set up the validation. For example, I have this:

```
  ngOnInit(){

this.detailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  exampleField: ['', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.maxLength(32),
    Validators.minLength(10)
  ])]
});
}
```

Instead of 'hard coding' the validators into my component like this, how can I set them from a configuration object, i.e. something like:

```
fieldData = {
  exampleField: {
    value: 'default value!',
    validators: ['required', 'minLength:10']
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Amal for your answer. Following the discussion, here is the full code in my component, which is still unfortunately producing the error `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, Injector, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { EntryService } from '../../_services/entry.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-input',
  templateUrl: './text-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-input.component.scss']
})
export class TextInputComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() id: number;
  @Input() field_name: string;
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() value: string;

  public fieldData;
  public detailsForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
      private injector: Injector,
      public _entryService: EntryService,
      private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    ) {
    this.id = this.injector.get('id');
    this.field_name = this.injector.get('field_name');
    this.label = this.injector.get('label');
    this.value = this.injector.get('value');
  }

  populateValidatorsList(valObj): any[] {
    const list = [];
    if (valObj['pattern']) { list.push(Validators.pattern(valObj['pattern'])); }
    if (valObj['maxLength']) { list.push(Validators.maxLength(valObj['maxLength'])); }
    if (valObj['minLength']) { list.push(Validators.minLength(valObj['minLength'])); }
    if (valObj['required']) { list.push(Validators.required); }
    return list;
  }

  ngOnInit(){

    this.fieldData = {
      exampleField: {
        value: 'default value!',
        validators: {
          required: true,
          minLength: 10,
          pattern: /I_NEED_PATTERN_CHECK/,
          maxLength: null
        }
      }
    }

    this.detailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      exampleField: [this.fieldData['exampleField']['value'], this.populateValidatorsList()]
  // exampleField: [this.fieldData['exampleField']['value'], [...this.populateValidatorsList()]]   // BOTH OF THESE ALSO 
  // exampleField: [this.fieldData['exampleField']['value'], [this.populateValidatorsList()]]      // PRODUCE THE SAME ERROR!
    });

}
```

Comment: you need to write a routing that returns field data in the expected format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you slightly modify your config object to something like this,

```
fieldData = {
  exampleField: {
    value: 'default value!',
    validators: {
     required: true,
     minLength: 10,
     pattern: /I_NEED_PATTERN_CHECK/,
     minLength: null
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your component have a method that processes this `validators` property from the config object.

```
populateValidatorsList(valObj): any[] {
 const list = [];
 if (valObj['pattern']) { list.push(Validators.pattern(valObj['pattern'])); }
 if (valObj['maxLength']) { list.push(Validators.maxLength(valObj['maxLength'])); }
 if (valObj['minLength']) { list.push(Validators.minLength(valObj['minLength'])); }
 if (valObj['required']) { list.push(Validators.required); }
 return list;
}

ngOnInit() {
 this.detailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  exampleField: [this.fieldData['exampleField']['value'], [...this.populateValidatorsList(this.fieldData['exampleField']['validators'])]]
 });
}
```

You could even add custom validations using this way. Just create another `.ts` file (like `validations.ts`) and have it contain all the custom validation `functions`. It is not a `class`, just a set of `export`ed functions grouped together obeying Custom validation function [rules](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators). Then you can have another property in the config.validators like,

```
validators: {
 required: true,
 minLength: 10,
 pattern: /I_NEED_PATTERN_CHECK/,
 minLength: null,
 custVal: 'custCheckForFoo'
}
```

> validators.ts

```
export function custCheckForFoo(c: AbstractControl) { 
 // validation check 
 // return null or errors object
}
```

Import this function in your component as,

```
import * as fromValidators from '../validators'
```

Use it in your `populateValidatorsList()` as an additional check,

```
if (valObj['custVal']) { list.push(fromValidators[valObj['custVal']]); }
```

Comment: Thanks, Amal. This is pretty good! Not *quite* ideal, because I do still have to hard code the validator names into the component with the `if` statements. I guess i can live with it, but I wonder if there's any way around that..?

Comment: you can go around that by relying on strictly naming your properties in the config and using some sort of pattern/regex checks on those properties to determine whether you need to add a `Validator` function/property from the inbuilt `Validators` or from a custom validation file.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, thanks. I've just had the chance to try this (the first method). I think on the line `...this.populateValidatorsList()` you meant to pass `this.fieldData['exampleField']['validators']` as an argument, right? However, I'm getting the error `TypeError: v is not a function` in my console.. not sure why...

Comment: No, `...` is the `spread` operator in ES6. It is meant to be used as it is. No passing of anything there. (assuming `populateValidatorsList()` is part of the component so that you could call it using `this`)

Comment: I didn't know that! But, without using an argument, I get the error `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`. Yes, I'm using that method as part of the component.

Comment: Could you show your line for that here. May be it is some semantics/syntactical  issue

Comment: Yes, this is the line: `    this.detailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      exampleField: [this.fieldData['exampleField']['value'], [...this.populateValidatorsList()]]
    });` The populateValidatorsList method is exactly as per your example.

Comment: try removing `[]` and `...` on the `populateValidatorsList()` as in, `this.detailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({ exampleField: [this.fieldData['exampleField']['value'], this.populateValidatorsList()] });`. See if that helped.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Amal. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error... Please see the edit to the OP where I have added the full code for my component. Thanks.

Comment: @Inigo I'm sorry, didn't know what I was thinking (was working on something else as well) when I replied. You're right, you need to pass the 'validators' object from the 'fieldData' object to 'populateValidatorsList()'.

Comment: No problem- simpler than I thought in the end! Working nicely now, many thanks for your help :)

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my answer as well to include the change.